# Pattern need to create

Tags: excel, vba

Can you please solve below given matrix for me in vba.

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
3 4 5
4 5
5
```

Thanks in advance for your support.

```
Sub pattern()
Dim i as byte
Dim j as byte

For i=1 to 5

 Cells(i,1).value=i

  For j=i to 5

    Cells(j,i).value=j

 Next i

End sub
```

Comment: Your code is missing a `Next j`

Comment: If you're interested, this could be done using formula as well in Office 365: `=LET(s,SEQUENCE(5)+SEQUENCE(,5,0),IF(s>5,"",s))`. Note that this will spill some extra blanks for the sequences not starting at 1.

Answer (score 1):

The following would produce the pattern you provided:

```
Sub pattern()

    Dim i As Byte
    Dim j As Byte
    
    For i = 1 To 5
        
        For j = i To 5
        
            Cells(i, j - (i - 1)).Value = j
        
        Next j
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]